# Is it possible to modify firebase functions config variables through an API?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to programmatically modify the variables of the firebase functions config object. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have to use the Firebase CLI to deploy configurations along with your functions.  You can't change configurations independently of your function code - they are all deployed at the same time.

If you need to dynamically change the configuration of your function, consider instead loading them from some other source, such as a database.

Comment: Thank you, Doug. That makes sense.